# R: how to find factor variables within a regression formula?

Tags: r, formula

Suppose I have the following regression formula `reg_formula`.
How can I find out that the variable `company` is used as factor variable?

```
reg_formula <- invest ~ market + stock + factor(company)
```

To be more precice, I am looking for some function `find_factor_vars` that would give me `company` as output:

```
find_factor_vars(reg_formula)
#company
```

Comment: do you mean if `factor` is not in the formula? you need a data set

Comment: no, I mean it exactly the way I have formulated the question: if `factor` IS used in the formula, how can I identify those variables that are used as factor variables? In my example, `company` would be the final output.

Comment: Try `mod$xlevels`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> find_factor_vars <- function(reg_formula,data_name)
+ {
+   model <- lm(eval(reg_formula),data = data_name)
+   factor.variable <- names(model$xlevels)
+   return(factor.variable)
+ }
> 
> find_factor_vars(expression(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Species+factor(Petal.Width)),iris)
[1] "Species"             "factor(Petal.Width)"
```

Comment: Please clarify your goal clearly. Your statement shows that you want to identify the type of variables which are either numeric variable or categorical variable (factor).

Comment: I have changed the answer

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this approach does not solve my issue due to two reasons: 1. your function requires running `lm` and using `model$xlevels` - this does not work in my case because my code uses `plm`, which does not report `model$xlevels`. 2. your final output is "factor(Petal.Width)" but I need "Petal.Width".  Due to these reasons, I am looking for a more general function that uses only `reg_formula` as input.